# NetLogo making breed spawn in certain patches

Tags: patch, netlogo

I'm very new to NetLogo and have what I hope to be a simple enough problem. I have two breeds created `[ redteam redsoldier]` & `[blueteam bluesoldier]` what I'm trying to do is make the different breeds spawn in specific patches. So red team can only randomly spawn in one of half (red territory) of the window and the blue team randomly spawns in the other (blue territory), however after trying multiple if and while statements and other things, the turtles only spawn in the center of the screen.

Any ideas?

```
globals [
red-patches
blue-patches 
]

;; note patches could not be set to only green as this partly clashed with soldiers     uniform

breed [ redteam redsoldier]
breed [ blueteam bluesoldier]

to setup
clear-all
setup-turtles
setup-patches
reset-ticks
end

to setup-turtles
create-redteam 10
 [
   set shape "person soldier" ;;need to import person soldier shape!
   setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
   set size 1.5
 ]

create-blueteam 10
 [
   set shape "person soldier" 
   setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
   set size 1.5
 ]
 end

to setup-patches
;; create red territory
set red-patches patches with [pycor < 0]
ask red-patches [ set pcolor green - 3 ]

;; create blue territory
set blue-patches patches with [pycor > 0]
ask blue-patches [ set pcolor green - 2 ]  
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use [`sprout`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sprout).

Here is a new version of `setup-turtles` (that needs to be called *after* `setup-patches`):

```
to setup-turtles
  ask n-of 10 red-patches [
    sprout-redteam 1 [
      set shape "person soldier"
      set size 1.5
    ]
  ]
  ask n-of 10 blue-patches [
    sprout-blueteam 1 [
      set shape "person soldier"
      set size 1.5
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I click the set up button. With `n-of 10 red-patches` highlighted as the error. The error code is `N-OF expected input to be a list or agentset but got the number 0 instead.
error while observer running N-OF
  called by procedure SETUP-TURTLES
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'setup'`

Comment: Sounds like `red-patches` might not have been initialized yet (`0` is the default value for NetLogo global variables). Have you called `setup-patches` *before* calling `setup-turtles`?

Comment: Yes `setup-patches` has been called before `setup-patches`. So it could possibly be the initialization you mentioned. I don't know what this could be in the source code for Globals red-patches is simply defined as `globals [
 red-patches
]`. Any other manipulation of red-patches is done in the setup-patches procedure.

Comment: Urgh. Turned out to be a simple problem that I missed. Your initial solution worked perfectly. Thanks for the help Nicolas!

Comment: If you could help with a follow up question. My two breeds when spawned into the patches can sometimes go off the screen. Is there a way to limit them to spawn randomly up to the edges of the patch? It happens only on the top and bottom. Its like one part of the soldier spawns at the top and the rest of it is at the bottom.

Comment: Follow up questions are usually better asked as separate questions on StackOverflow. That being said, I think turning world-wrapping off in your model's settings might be just what you are looking for.